# jQuery: Count number of child elements inside a div, update number when element added/removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding child elements inside a div using append() and counting/adding a number to each one using ++ to +1 each time an item is added.

I want the value to automatically adjust if an item is removed, for example if I have 4 elements:

- Element #1
- Element #2
- Element #3
- Element #4

Currently if element #3 is removed the list looks like this:

- Element #1
- Element #2
- Element #4

But I want it to look like this:

- Element #1
- Element #2
- Element #3

Appreciate any advice on what I should use to achieve this, thanks.

Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/wepsrzkm/

```
var price_rule_html = '<button class="remove_price_rule button" type="button">Remove Element</button>';
var price_rule_count = 1;

var price_rule_count = jQuery(".price_rule_area_1").children().length;

jQuery('.add_price_rule').click(function () {

price_rule_count++;
jQuery('.price_rule_area_1').append('<div class="price_rule_wrapper"><div class="price_rule_count">Element #<span>' + price_rule_count + '</span></div>' + price_rule_html + '</div>');

jQuery(".remove_price_rule").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parents('.price_rule_wrapper').remove();   
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Decrease `price_rule_count` by 1 when removing.
2. After remove one element, alter the existing elements `#number`.
   UPDATED: As from [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32690190/1737627)'s answer, we don't need to traverse all the left elements, only need to change those which are after the removed one's text.
3. The origin code will register multiple events to `.remove_price_rule` each time you add a item, that means if you create the element 3 times, when you remove one, the logic in the remove handler will execute 3 times, so the `price_rule_count` will be inconsistent to the actual counts if we use `price_rule_count--`, however, even if we use `jQuery(".price_rule_area_1").children().length;` to get real count, its stll redundant to execute the same logic many times. 
   So It's better to use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)'s delegate form here.

```js
var price_rule_html = '<button class="remove_price_rule button" type="button">Remove Element</button>';
var price_rule_count = jQuery(".price_rule_area_1").children().length;

jQuery('.add_price_rule').click(function () {
     
 price_rule_count++;
 jQuery('.price_rule_area_1').append('<div class="price_rule_wrapper"><div class="price_rule_count">Element #<span>' + price_rule_count + '</span></div>' + price_rule_html + '</div>');
});

+jQuery('.price_rule_area_1').on("click", ".remove_price_rule", function() {
  
  // As from Arun P Johny's answer, we only need to change the text after the removed element.
  $element =  jQuery(this).parents('.price_rule_wrapper');
  $element
       .nextAll('.price_rule_wrapper')
       .find('span')
       .text(function(index, prevText) {
            return parseInt(prevText, 10) - 1;
        });
  
  
  jQuery(this).parents('.price_rule_wrapper').remove();
  --price_rule_count;
   
  // This would be slower as some elements don't need to be traversed.
  // jQuery('.price_rule_wrapper').each(function(idx) {
  //     $(this).find(".price_rule_count > span").text(idx + 1);
  // });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price_rule_area_1"></div>
<button class="button-primary add_price_rule" type="button">Add Element</button>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wepsrzkm/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that doesn't work. For example: click "Add Element" 4 times, remove "Element #2", then click "Add Element" and the fourth element is labelled as "Element #2" instead of "Element #4".

Answer (score 0):

You are binding multiple event handler for each remove element

```js
var price_rule_html = '<button class="remove_price_rule button" type="button">Remove Element</button>';
var price_rule_count = 1;
var price_rule_count = jQuery(".price_rule_area_1").children().length;

jQuery('.add_price_rule').click(function() {
  price_rule_count++;
  jQuery('.price_rule_area_1').append('<div class="price_rule_wrapper"><div class="price_rule_count">Element #<span>' + price_rule_count + '</span></div>' + price_rule_html + '</div>');
});

$('div.price_rule_area_1').on('click', '.remove_price_rule', function() {
  // event handler for dynamically generated element
  jQuery(this).parents('.price_rule_wrapper')
    .nextAll('div')
    // get all div after the removing div
    .find('span')
    // get number span inside it
    .html(function(i, v) {
      return parseInt(v) - 1;
    })
    // decrementing value of it
    .end().end()
    // get back to the removing div
    .remove();
  // removing the div
  price_rule_count--;
  //  decrementing the count by 1 after removing the element
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price_rule_area_1"></div>
<button class="button-primary add_price_rule" type="button">Add Element</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that doesn't work. If you add a few elements, and then remove them the numbers are all incorrect, and it goes into minus values.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the content of the `span` element inside the `price_rule_wrapper` element like

```js
var price_rule_html = '<button class="remove_price_rule button" type="button">Remove Element</button>';
var price_rule_count = 1;

var price_rule_count = jQuery(".price_rule_area_1").children().length;

jQuery('.add_price_rule').click(function() {
  price_rule_count++;
  jQuery('.price_rule_area_1').append('<div class="price_rule_wrapper"><div class="price_rule_count">Element #<span>' + price_rule_count + '</span></div>' + price_rule_html + '</div>');
});

jQuery('.price_rule_area_1').on('click', ".remove_price_rule", function() {
  var $wrapper = jQuery(this).closest('.price_rule_wrapper');
  $wrapper.nextAll('.price_rule_wrapper').find('span').text(function(i, text) {
    return text - 1
  })
  $wrapper.remove();
  price_rule_count--;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price_rule_area_1"></div>
<button class="button-primary add_price_rule" type="button">Add Element</button>
```

Note: Use event delegation to handler the click event of dynamically recreated elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this seems to be almost working. But if you add a 5 elements, then remove 3, then add some more elements the counter doesn't label the elements correctly, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle, I have used CSS counters in order to automatically keep your element number:
https://jsfiddle.net/wepsrzkm/8/

```
.price_rule_area_1{
   counter-reset: section; 
}
.price_rule_area_1 .price_rule_wrapper{
    counter-increment: section; 
}
.price_rule_area_1 .price_rule_wrapper .price_rule_count::after{
    content: "#"counter(section);
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this mate

```
<html>

<body>

<div class="price_rule_area_1"></div>
<button class="button-primary add_price_rule" type="button">Add Element</button>

</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var price_rule_html = '<button class="remove_price_rule button" type="button">Remove Element</button>';
var price_rule_count = 1;



jQuery('.add_price_rule').click(function () {
    var price_rule_count = jQuery(".price_rule_area_1").children().length;    
    price_rule_count++;
    jQuery('.price_rule_area_1').append('<div class="price_rule_wrapper"><div class="price_rule_count">Element #<span class="bull ">' + price_rule_count + '</span></div>' + price_rule_html + '</div>');

    jQuery(".remove_price_rule").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).parents('.price_rule_wrapper').remove();   
        price_rule_count--;
        alert(jQuery('.price_rule_area_1').children().length)
        jQuery('.price_rule_area_1').children().eq(price_rule_count-1).find('.bull').text(price_rule_count)


    });

});
</script>
</html>
```